# Django executing different url

Tags: python, django

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include("dashboardapp.urls")),
]
```

template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<body>
<style>
h2 {text-align: center;}


.center {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 40px;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #f2f2f2;}
</style>


  <h2>Summary Details</h2>
  <table class="center">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>scrapper_id</th>
      <th>scrapper_jobs_log_id</th>
      <th>external_job_source_id</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for stud in scrappers %}
    {% csrf_token %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{stud.scrapper_id}}</td>
        <td>{{stud.scrapper_jobs_log_id}}</td>
        <td>{{stud.external_job_source_id}}</td>

      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

My terminal is showing

> Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/.

But when I click the url its changing to different url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/sales`. But my url has no sales/. but my other project has sales/. Can anybody help with the solution for this

Comment: check have you started your project and other project? on which port your project is running and other one

Comment: @sahasrara62 I have run that project and terminated using CTL+C

Comment: please provide template related to this url